# Issue with Dictionary type, If gived a specific text then get the equivalent dictionary key or dictionary value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, dictionary

I have a dictionary(of string, string), I use the dictionary values to set a directory path, and the Keys to set a description for each value.

Por example:

```
Value of a random item of my dictionary: "C:\Test"
Key name of that item = "Test folder"
```

well, now in my application I have a option to choose if I prefer to show the descriptions or the full directory paths, and here is the problem...

Some images to understand it:

1 - Here I store/manage the items of my dictionary:

[image]

2 - I can toogle this checkbox to show the dictionary keys or the dictionary values in a combobox (wich you will see in the next image):

[image]

3 - Descriptions checkbox is CHECKED, then descriptions are displayed in the combobox, and when I add a item, it be added with the selected combobox.text (which can be the description or the full path)

[image]

4 - Now I uncheck the description checkbox, and what I want is to change the descriptions of the listview as the same way I changed the descriptions of the combobox to the equivalent  full paths (But what I do to change the combobox names is to reload the dictionary because is alphabetically sorted so...I don't know how to do the same with the listview subitems)

[image]

I want to remember you that the listview subitem text can be the description or it can be the full path, so I need to do this change thinking in both alternatives.

...And here is my code:

(Read the comments please)

```
    ' First of all
    ' "Item.SubItems(2).Text" can be the description or it can be the full path, so I need to do it with both alternatives

    If ListView_Monitor.Items.Count <> 0 Then

        For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView_Monitor.Items

            If ShowDescriptions Then ' Showdescription is a boolean var to show descriptions or full paths

                ' Description is stored in the "Dictionary.Key"
                ' I don't know how to get the key name of the item

                ' Item.SubItems(2).Text = Directories_SendTo.keys  ... ...
                ' CType(Item.SubItems(2).Text, Directories_SendTo... ...)

            ElseIf Not ShowDescriptions Then ' Don't show descriptions, I will show fullpaths

                ' Fullpath is stored in the "Dictionary.Value"

                ' Remember that "Item.SubItems(2).Text" can be the description or the fullpath
                ' So if "Item.SubItems(2).Text" is the description then this piece of code works, 'cause the dictionary keyname is the same as the description name 
                Item.SubItems(2).Text = Directories_SendTo(Item.SubItems(2).Text)

                ' Here I need an alternative if "Item.SubItems(2).Text" is the directory path and not the description
            End If

        Next

    End If
```

> UPDATE:

The solution (for now)...

My question is if I can improve this piece of code (maybe to do not loop inside the dict):

```
        If ListView_Monitor.Items.Count <> 0 Then

            For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView_Monitor.Items

                If ShowDescriptions Then ' Show descriptions

                    For Each value In Directories_SendTo.Values
                        If value = Item.SubItems(2).Text Then
                            Item.SubItems(2).Text = FindKeyByValue(Directories_SendTo, Item.SubItems(2).Text)
                        End If
                    Next

                ElseIf Not ShowDescriptions Then ' Show fullpaths

                    For Each key In Directories_SendTo.Keys
                        If key = Item.SubItems(2).Text Then
                            Item.SubItems(2).Text = Directories_SendTo(key)
                        End If
                    Next

                End If

            Next

        End If

   Public Function FindKeyByValue(Of TKey, TValue)(dictionary As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue), value As TValue) As TKey

        For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) In dictionary
            If value.Equals(pair.Value) Then Return pair.Key
        Next

        ' Throw New Exception("The value is not found in the dictionary.")
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: Lots of graphics and lots of words. What is the question? Not a single question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, on how to improve the loop you are using, it can be significantly improved. At the moment, if you have 100 items in the list view and 10 items in the directories, your code will loop at least 1000 times and could loop up to 10 times that depending on the values that are used in directories and whether or not ShowDescriptions is flagged.

We can reduce the direct looping to 110 times by building a dictionary by the appropriate key prior to entering the assignment loop:

```
    If ListView_Monitor.Items.Count <> 0 Then
        Dim DirectoriesByCurrentKey As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        If ShowDescriptions Then
            ' If we are showing the descriptions, add each of the items to the new collection, keyed by the value
            For Each key In Directories_SendTo.Keys
                Dim Description As String
                Description = Directories_SendTo(key)
                ' We don't know if description is unique, so make sure that we don't get a runtime error if we 
                ' try to add the same description multiple time
                If Not DirectoriesByCurrentKey.ContainsKey(Description) Then
                    DirectoriesByCurrentKey.Add(Description, key)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            ' Just use the current collection
            DirectoriesByCurrentKey = Directories_SendTo
        End If

        For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView_Monitor.Items
            Dim sDescription As String = ""
            ' Try to find the current description using the current list item description
            If DirectoriesByCurrentKey.TryGetValue(Item.SubItems(2).Text, sDescription) Then
                ' If we found the entry, change the description to what we found
                Item.SubItems(2).Text = sDescription
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Note that because we don't know if the Description is unique or not, we need to test it's existence in the new dictionary prior to adding it. This will result in the same behavior as you currently have, since your FindKeyByValue stops at the first match.

Answer (score 1):

If this were my application, I would change the UI element to a datagridview so that I could bind a collection containing a custom class and just hide or show the appropriate columns as needed.

This approach will allow you to easily add additional property columns in the future without worrying about the problems you are currently facing. It would also allow you to extend the UI to other platforms (mobile, web) without a lot of hard-coded information in the UI.

For example, I would create the following class and collection to hold info about the files:

```
Public Class FileDetails
    Public Property Index As Integer
    Public Property Description As String = String.Empty
    Public Property FullFileName As String = String.Empty
    Public ReadOnly Property FileName As String
        Get
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.FullFileName) Then
                Return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Me.FullFileName)
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Directory As String
        Get
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.FullFileName) Then
                Return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Me.FullFileName)
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class FileDetailsCollection
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of FileDetails)

End Class
```

Here is the private member variable that I would declare at the form level to hold the information:

```
Private m_Collection As FileDetailsCollection
```

This method is used to populate the collection with some sample data:

```
Private Sub LoadCollection()
    Dim wIndex As Integer
    m_Collection = New FileDetailsCollection
    For Each sFileName As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\", "*.*")
        Dim oFileDetails As New FileDetails

        oFileDetails.FullFileName = sFileName
        wIndex += 1
        oFileDetails.Index = wIndex
        oFileDetails.Description = "Test " & wIndex.ToString

        m_Collection.Add(oFileDetails)
    Next
End Sub
```

This method performs the initial configuration on the grid, including definition of the columns that will be shown:

```
Private Sub ConfigureGrid()
    With Me.DataGridView1
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        .Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "Index", .Name = .DataPropertyName, .HeaderText = "Index"})
        .Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "FullFileName", .Name = .DataPropertyName, .HeaderText = "Song"})
        .Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "Description", .Name = .DataPropertyName, .HeaderText = "Description"})
        .Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "Directory", .Name = .DataPropertyName, .HeaderText = "Description"})

        .DataSource = m_Collection
    End With
End Sub
```

This method configures the visible columns for the current option change (this is equivalent to your checkbox):

```
Private Sub ConfigureColumnsForOptionChange()

    With Me.DataGridView1
        .Columns("Description").Visible = CheckBox1.Checked
        .Columns("Directory").Visible = Not CheckBox1.Checked
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, we perform the initialization and form startup:

```
Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Call LoadCollection()
    Call LoadGrid()
    Call ConfigureColumnsForOptionChange()

End Sub
```

and update the UI as the user changes the checkbox value:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Call ConfigureColumnsForOptionChange()
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your time but using a datagridview is not a option for me, I use a extendedl istview which I've coded with "internal" customizations like events and funcs, I don't want to try to rewrite that to a datagrid and to change the full code of the form. I think my little problem can be solved by using a ctype or some tryparse with the dictionary, but thankyou so much for your answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution I'm using, maybe you can tell me if I can improve it. really your code is so interesting to learn and to play with datagridviews but really I can't this time, thanks.